# formidable saves file without extension in Node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, formidable

```
    app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {    

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');    
    files = [],
    fields = [];
    form.on('field', function(field, value) {
        fields.push([field, value]);
    })
    form.on('file', function(field, file) {
        console.log(file.name);
        files.push([field, file]);
    })
    form.on('end', function() {
        console.log('done');
       // res.redirect('/forms');
    });
    form.parse(req);
});
```

UI used to upload multiple images in nodejs using **formidable**

The files are being creating. But the images are getting saved without extension.

[image]

Is there anything extra steps i have to do?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
form.keepExtensions = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `onPart`:

```
form.on('part', function (part) {
  if (part.filename) {
    if (!isInvalidFileName(part.filename) || !isInvalidMimeType(part.mime)) {
      files.push([part]);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: still not working. type is file. not images.in console i printed file names which is printed with extensions. console.log(file.name);